# Apache Commons CLI и киррилица

Tags: java, кириллица

При использовании в сообщении usage (с использованием библиотеки commons-cli от apache) кириллицы, она выводится на консоль "битой". При этом тут же сообщения через System.out.println выводятся без проблем.

Как можно исправить?

Answer (score 0):

Кодировка кириллицы на консоле обычно отличается от кодировки оси, в Windows это CP 1251, а в консоли CP 866.

Наберите на консоли:

```
СHCP
```

У меня он печатает:

> Active code page: 866